# error placing ad-tag in facebook application

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, ads

i have designed a facebook application, it does not show any error or warning in chrome inspector or in facebook insights page.

however when i add an add tag as shown below, i get the error. please let me know what is going wrong.

```
<html>
<sript> google analytics code here </script>
<!-- Begin Ad Call Tag - Do not Modify -->
<iframe width='468' height='60' frameborder='no' framespacing='0' scrolling='no'  src='http://ads.*******/fbslot/slot*****?ad_size=468x60&adkey=e37'></iframe>
<!-- End of Ad Call Tag -->
<?php
some code here
?>
</html>
```

error message in chrome inspector :

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://apps.facebook.com/statustics/ from frame with URL http://ads.********/fbslot/slot******?ad_size=468x60&adkey=e37. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook disallows Google Ads in facebook applications. You must use another Ad service.
Google and Facebook aren´t goot friends at all ;)

Comment: open your eyes and read, its written google analytics not ggle adsense

Comment: That was uncalled for. We all make mistakes! He's just trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think facebook blocks refrences to other domains in the iframe, including subdomains.
This is a cross-domain protection thing.

Comment: how about the ads you see in other apps?? had this been true there would not have been any ads running on any app.

Comment: I didn't say they block ads, I just said they block iframes from other domains (subdomains) inside the iframe. There are other ways to get ads on the page a side from inserting an iframe into an iframe and from another subdomain, no less.